# Real world goods in iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase

I've seen questions asked here before, but they do not address the issue.  That said:

"In App Purchases" specifically may not be real world goods or services, according to Apple's guidelines. What services allow integration with iPhone apps so that I can use ObjectiveC to sell things in an iPhone app?

In other words, how can I sell stuff in my app and not use a website or integrated UIWebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only process I can think of would be something like using an e-commerce app like Magento or Shopify and using the API to pull the product data, and then make HTTP requests to the site to simulate the ordering process.

Comment: To summarize, your iphone app will have to interact with a webservice to provide the data feeds you're looking for. It's the equivalent of the user visiting your website directly just instead it has an iphone app interface vs a website.

Comment: I've thought of this. I suppose I am looking for a site with a developer API.

Comment: Shopify, Big Commerce, and Magento all have GET or PULL API's which allow you to access orders already placed, but I don't know of any site that lets you PUT an order.